# How can I get a MySQL table into a Yahoo Pipe?

Tags: mysql, yahoo-pipes

I'm trying to get data I've got in a MySQL table into a Yahoo Pipe to experiment with what's possible with it. I'm happy to transmit the table over HTTP if necessary, has anybody any suggestions for a method- or is there a standard way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write a web service (or a handy api) to query database. Most probably Yahoo! Pipes don't support protocols except HTTP. Not possible unless you implement something. Here's an idea:

1. Get query via HTTP parameters.
2. Execute on database and get results as an array of rows in PHP.
3. Put column names and rows to a XML or JSON view and send to the client.
4. I'm not sure whether you can parse XML or JSON on Yahoo Pipes however if you can mimic RSS/ATOM types it wil work.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes don't support SQL type storage directly, it's all 'flat file' or JSON so conversion to and from may be an issue for the final use of the data client side.

They do have small storage pockets than can be accessed via the **YQL module** each has a maximum capacity of 100k and you can have 1000 of them for free.